# Chart.js: how to increase space between multiple Y axes on the same side?

Tags: chart.js

I have a line chart with multiple Y axes on the right side, but they're too close. The options I've applied are:

```
{
  scales: {
    yAxes: [
      {
        id: "GC",
        position: "right",
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: "Garbage Collection",
          fontSize: 15
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      },
      {
        id: "CPU",
        position: "right",
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: "CPU Usage",
          fontSize: 15
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          max: 100
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The result:

[image: Result]

How can I increase the space between multiple Y axes?

Comment: Unfortunately, the only way to do this is to extend the base scale type (these look like linear scales) and implement your own `draw()` method.  I have done something similar with the chart legend element.  The next time I have some time in front of a computer I'll submit an answer with an example of how to do this.  Maybe this comment will help you figure it out in the meantime.

Comment: Are you talking about the space between the text "Garbage Collection" and the axis of "CPU Usage"? I want it to be larger.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I'm away from my computer right now but ill submit an answer tomorrow.

Comment: I'm still working on this FYI.  It turned out to be more complex than I thought because of how the chart.js layout service works.  I'm currently able to extend the width of the first Y axis but haven't been able to force the title to paint in a different location (with the extended width it still paints at the far right of the width).